# Reading series of chars without arrays or strings

Tags: c++, string, input, char

i am struggling with one problem in my program. For input I am given ID that is series of 3 upper case letters, like `ABC`.
The problem is I have to read them somehow without using any other header file than `<iostream>` and I cannot use `string` nor any array types, such as `char[]` or `string[]`. How can I read series of multiple letters? Can I split them somehow into three chars?

The ID is needed later for implementation of the list - the three letters is an ID of a specific list and there will be also other lists, and the program basically will have to perform some operations on them such as adding elements, merging etc.

Thanks you for your help!

Comment: why you cannot use `string` or a character array? How do you want to store the characters if not in an array of characters?

Comment: so this ID input. how it's composed as ABC? a string an array? you stated that you can not use string or array but how the ID of ABC is put together without these what I don't get.

Comment: It is forbidden in the task's rules. User inputs ABC, but you cannot use string in the whole code and cannot use any arrays. If you do, submission of the program will be declined.

Comment: There's an answer proposing the use of `stdio`. Do you know if that's also disallowed?

Comment: Yes, only `iostream` is allowed unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Strange requirements but just read them one at a time into separate variables.

```
char a = cin.get();
char b = cin.get();
char c = cin.get();
```

`get` reads a single character.

Comment: I don't know why, but my program ends after I type `S ABC` for example. It should enter the if statement and then get 3 letters and repeat the loop. What is wrong?

`do{
  cin >> operation;
  
  if(operation == 'S'){
   
   char sn1 = cin.get();
   char sn2 = cin.get();
   char sn3 = cin.get();
   
  }
  
  else if(operation == 'B'){
   
   char kr1 = cin.get();
   char kr2 = cin.get();
   char kr3 = cin.get();
   
  }  
  
 }while(operation == 'F');
`

Comment: @feetl0ver I'm not sure, but the error in the code above is that you are reading the space as your first character, `cin >> operation;` reads the S but it does not read the space, so your first get will read that space. That probably explains why things are going wrong.

Comment: Do you have an idea how to fix this so it skips that space?

Comment: Well if there is always one space, then all you need to do is add another `cin.get()` to read the space (`cin.ignore()` would also do the same thing). If you could have multiple spaces it's a little more complicated but not much.

Answer (score 0):

U can use scanf() or printf() methods.

Comment: How would you use `printf` there?